# How to change the caption of all controls on a form? [C++ Builder]

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder

I want to set the caption to all controls (Tlabel, Tbutton, Teditlabel, Tbitbtn, TGroupBox, etc) and all components (TMenuItems, TActions) that have a caption from a language file.

My problem is that Caption is not public in TComponent, TControl or even TWinControl. Even more, some 'common' controls like TLabel/TBitBtn are not even derived from TWinControl.

Example:

```
void SetCaptionAll(TComponent *container)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < container->ComponentCount; i++)
      {
      TComponent *child = container->Components[i];
      child->Caption = ReadFromFile;    <-- This won't work. Caption is private
      }
}
```

Most important: I don't want to use a macro (I think this is what is called) like:

```
#define GetCtrlCaption(p)\
{ code here }
```

because this is not debugable.

I need C++ Builder example, but Delphi is accepted also.

Comment: Isn't it easier to just add language version ? (Project->Languages->Add)

Comment: @Vancalar - Yes, might be. But I write code for a large/old application. It is already like this. I cannot use Project->Languages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for all TControl descendants:

```
 for i := 0 to ControlCount - 1  do
    Controls[i].SetTextBuf('CommonText');
```

To walk through all controls including ones at childs like panels, you can use recursive traversal:

```
procedure SetControlText(Site: TWinControl; const s: string);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Site.ControlCount - 1  do begin
     Site.Controls[i].SetTextBuf(PWideChar(s));
     if Site.Controls[i] is TWinControl then
       SetControlText(TWinControl(Site.Controls[i]), s);
  end;
end;

begin
   SetControlText(Self, 'CommonText');
```

For components like `TMenuItems` you can use RTTI - check whether component has property like `Caption, Text` etc and set new string.

Delphi RTTI example using old-style approach (new RTTI is available since D2010). Not sure that it [works for Builder](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Working_with_RTTI)

```
 uses... TypInfo

 if IsPublishedProp(Site.Controls[i], 'Caption') then
   SetStrProp(Site.Controls[i], 'Caption', 'Cap');
```

Comment: Delphi help quote: "The SetTextBuf method is provided for backwards compatibility only. To set the text of a control now, assign a string value to the Text property."

Comment: But `Text` is `protected` property, it is not available without casting you wanted to avoid

Comment: Do you know why SetTextBuf  was deprecated? Is it safe to use in modern programs? If so, I will stick to it,

Comment: Perhaps due to multiplatform perspective - `SetTextBuf` is based on Windows control message concept

Comment: SetTextBuf('abc') will change the number in a TSpinEdit to "abc". Any pointers on how to check if a TControl has a Caption property using RTTI ?

Comment: AFAIK, Delphi RTTI differs from Builder approach. Base page refers to some C++ ones: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Working_with_RTTI

Comment: Delphi RTTI certainly differs from C++Builder's RTTI (I asked about that only a few days ago), but the components are in Delphi and so GetPublishedProp, which is also Delphi, might work too.

Comment: In general, `TypInfo.hpp` and `Rtti.hpp` methods do work on VCL controls in C++Builder. But, there have been known RTTI generation bugs in C++Builder in various versions, so it *may* be worth adding a Delphi Pascal source file to your C++Builder project (yes, you can do that) and perform the RTTI work from Pascal instead of from C++. Though the VCL components in question are implemented in Delphi, so the RTTI will likely work correctly in C++ without having to resort to that